# Very simple call to WebRequest to call a web service is somehow making two calls every time, one without credentials and one with?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, json.net, httpwebrequest

I'm calling Shopify's API with a Key/Password and this very basic method call is somehow making two calls every time.  I'm using "Charles Proxy" to snoop the calls and everything it does is double, one with auth and one without.

Look at the screenshots. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public string GetJsonReply(string _requestURL)
    {
        string json;

        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(_requestURL);
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(APIKey, Password);

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            json = e.GetBaseException().ToString();
        }

        return json;
    }
```

[image: Failed Call]

[image: Successful Call]

**EDIT:** The method is invoked like this:

```
public IdBillingContract GetBillingAddressInfo(string _id)
{
    string url = "https://myurl.myshopify.com/admin/orders/" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_id) + ".json?fields=id,billing_address";
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IdBillingContract>(GetJsonReply(url), _serializerSettings);
}
```

Comment: where is the call to this method located `GetJsonReply(string _requestURL)` and how is it Invoked..? if this is a web page, perhaps you have some `Postback issues happening meaning it's calling Page_Load twice for instance.. can you show how it's being called

Comment: Which request occurs first: the one with auth or the one without?  What data is contained in your `json` string?

Comment: The one without auth occurs first. And I edited the question with the method I use to invoke it, which is in the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the `Credentials` property. Don't use it, because .NET is cycling through in the background attempting the different authentication protocols such as NTLM etc...

```
public string GetJsonReply(string _requestURL)
{
    string json = string.Empty;
    string apiKey = "Foo";
    string password = "Bar";

    string credentialsFormatted = string.Format("{0}:{1}",apiKey,password);
    byte[] credentialBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentialsFormatted);
    string basicCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBytes);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_requestURL);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + basicCredentials;

    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        json = e.GetBaseException().ToString();
    }

   return json;
}
```